# How can I place a link at the beginning of a string in Jekyll?

Tags: markdown, jekyll

I'm trying to place some links in a static site using Jekyll + Markdown as follows:

```
  - role: Scrum Master - Project Manager
    time: SEP 2019 - PRESENT
    company: [Vincae](https://vincae.com/), Brazil
    details: |
      Responsible for implementing and maintaining a scrum methodology during the development of Unreal Engine based games like [Pure Forge](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1060160/PureForge).
```

I have no problem with my second link in "details" but my first link under "company" is trowing the following error:

```
         Error: (C:/Users/raschmitt/Dropbox/Public/Coding/Jekyll/online-cv/_data/data.yml): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 92 column 5
         Error: Run jekyll build --trace for more information.
```

What an I doing wrong an how can I correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YML parsing doesn't like reserved characters in unquoted string. Here it's certainly the colon ':'.

In order to avoid reserved characters collision, simply quote or double quote your string :

```
  - role: Scrum Master - Project Manager
    time: SEP 2019 - PRESENT
    company: '[Vincae](https://vincae.com/), Brazil'
    details: |
      blah
      blah
```

And output with `{{ m.company | markdownify }}`

Comment: I tried it: https://github.com/raschmitt/raschmitt.github.io/blob/master/_data/data.yml#L94

And as you can see here: https://raschmitt.github.io/

It just literally outputted the syntax without placing the link.

Comment: In https://github.com/raschmitt/raschmitt.github.io/blob/master/_includes/experiences.html#L22, you must read `{{ experience.company | markdownify }}`.